# How to set Content-Disposition header using Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am serving an image using the Django REST framework. Unfortunately it downloads instead of displays. I guess I have to set the header `Content-Disposition = 'inline'`. How do I do this in the `View` or the `Renderer`?

```
class ImageRenderer(renderers.BaseRenderer):
    media_type = 'image/*'
    format = '*'
    charset = None
    render_style = 'binary'

    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        return data

class ImageView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (ImageRenderer, )

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        image=MyImage.objects.get(id=1)
        image_file = image.thumbnail_png.file
        return Response(image)
```

Comment: Are you sure media type validation accepts wildcards? Have you tried `image/jpeg' just to verify?

Comment: @Ken4scholars, your right, when I put image/png it displays without downloading.Is there a way to get the renderer to work with jpg and png?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment) in the Django docs, you can set the `Content-Disposition` header in this way:

```
response = Response(my_data, content_type='image/jpeg')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="foo.jpeg"'
```

Comment: This fails if the filename contains non-ascii characters.

Answer (score 1):

Django 4.2 included a `django.utils.http.content_disposition_header()` to handle the encoding and formatting of the header for you. [See docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.content_disposition_header)